# Is Elastic/Metricbeats suitable for process monitoring and alerting?

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

Do you use Elastic and Metricbeats for process monitoring and alerting? How did you configure your data gathering and alerting?

I am currently trying to set this up, and running into some basic issues. These issues are making me question whether Elastic is a suitable tool for alerting. Here is my planned setup:

- Use Metricbeats to gather process data
- Create an Elastic dashboard/lens for certain processes
- If the `process.cpu.start_time` from Metricbeats is very young (e.g. it has only been running for under 5 minutes), alert!

I have been working my way through this using the following approach:

- From Metricbeats, the processes include `process.cpu.start_time`, as a text string in ISO date format. Elastic lens queries are very limited with dates.
- Workaround: use Logstash to create a filter field `process.cpu.start_epoch`, which is an integer - the Unix epoch: "seconds since January 1, 1970".
- Create a dashboard lens, querying only my process, and only the `last` metric. This works and gives me "the time that the process started, as a Unix epoch".
- I next need to calculate the time difference between `now` and that integer. However I don't see anything in the lens documentation about doing date math. So I'm stuck.

The difficulties I am encountering are making me wonder if I am "doing it wrong"? Is Elastic/Metricbeats a suitable tool for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: find the right hammer!

What I needed is called "Elastic runtime fields". There's a step-by-step writeup here: https://elastic-content-share.eu/elastic-runtime-field-example-repository/

Summary:

- open index
- click the "dots"
- choose "add field to index pattern"
- set output field name as desired

  - for me this is `process.cpu.start.age`
- set output type

  - for me this is "long"
- write your script in "painless"

  - for me this is  `emit(Date().getTime() - doc['process.cpu.start'].value.toEpochMilli());`

PS: I deleted my logstash filters, because they were superfluous.